# How to make git diff treat a file as binary _only sometimes_

Tags: git, binary, diff

I work with .xib files which are XML. Most often, I want to treat them as a binary file, because changes tend to be non-human-readable and spread over many parts of the file. Thus, I've set up my .git/info/attributes file like so:

```
*.xib -diff
```

So far so good, but sometimes I *do* want to see the full diff. Currently, I have to go into the `.gitattributes` and remove the *.xib rule. Lame! What I'd really like is to be able to use an alias (e.g. `git fulldiff`) or a git-diff argument (e.g. `git diff --xib`) to let it know that, no, in this case it should treat *.xib files like normal. Or maybe just ignore all attributes, since I don't have any other attributes in that file as of now.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can indeed override the contents of .gitattributes thusly:

```
git diff --text
```

Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you to the coworker who pointed this out to me!